# Make wordpress comments work with include templatepath

Tags: comments

How can I make the wordpress comments work with:

```
include(TEMPLATEPATH."/comments.php");
```

instead of:

```
comments_template( '', true );
```

Ay ideas? Ty

Comment: why do you want to do that? answer is probably you can't do it anyway; `comments_template()` is actually checking and preparing a lot of needed stuff before calling the comments.php file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: you *can't*.

Longer answer:

You can *include* `comments.php` as a *template-part* file inside another template, via:

```
get_template_part( 'comments.php' )
```

...but that won't actually make comments *work*, because the `comments_template()` template tag does far more than merely include the `comments.php` template-part file. In order to make comments actually *work* when using `get_template_part()` as opposed to `comments_template()`, you'd need to duplicate [all of the functions performed by `comments_template()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.1/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L851). And if you need to duplicate all of that code in order to make comments *work*, you might as well just use the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

That wont work because we cannot include the `comments.php` file as a template file. Our `comments.php` file doesn't contain the necessary codes to do SQL operations on database and fetch the comments to display.

So instead including that file as a template file we should call the function `comments_template()` to show the comments.

Wordpress uses [`comments_template()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.1/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L825) function to get the file and display the comments, if we don't provide file variable wordpress uses default `comments.php` to process the result.

> #### Note -
>
> If you're curious about how to load a different comment template then here's the code

```
<?php comments_template( '/comments2.php' ); ?>
```

Reference - [Comments_template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template)